# data.table efficient duplication count

Tags: r, performance, data.table

Using data.table I can use unique(mydt) to tell me which rows are the unique rows. I am interested in finding out how many times a row was duplicated. For example

```
require(data.table)

data.table(x = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'),
           y = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4))
```

should find out the unique rows are

```
   x y
1: a 1
2: a 2
3: b 3
4: b 4
```

and also that the row (a, 1) has 2 duplicate rows. So far I have come up with

```
mydt.colnames = colnames(mydt)
mydt.fweighted = mydt[,
                      list(fweight = .N),
                      by = mydt.colnames]
```

But this seems to be very slow, and it isn't using the unique function at all. Is there a fast way to accomplish this with unique?

Comment: Do you need it for a data table? or a data.frame works?

Comment: What are the dimensions of your data that this is 'very slow'?

Comment: I just tried 4M rows, 30 vars and it completed in under 2 seconds.

Comment: is `mydt[unique(mydt), on=colnames(mydt), .N, by=.EACHI]` any faster for you? It seems to shave a fraction off over here.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the fastest way. Maybe you need to upgrade. `.N` has been optimized since 1.9.8 ... https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#new-features-2

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
require(data.table)
data.table(x = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'),
           y = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4))

sapply(1:nrow(unique(Table[,1])), function(x) 
length(which(Table[,1] == as.character(unique(Table[,1])[x]))))
```

For your example this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Testing on larger data sets:

```
n <- 2e6
set.seed(1)
mydt <- data.table(x = sample(LETTERS, n, replace = T),
                   y = sample(1:10, n, replace = T))


JCWong <- function(mydt) {
  mydt.colnames <- colnames(mydt)
  mydt.fweighted <- mydt[, list(N = .N), by = mydt.colnames]
  mydt.fweighted
}

thelatemail <- function(mydt) {
  mydt.fweighted2 <- mydt[unique(mydt), on = colnames(mydt), .N, by = .EACHI]
  mydt.fweighted2
}

all.equal(JCWong(mydt),  thelatemail(mydt))
# [1] TRUE

require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(JCWong(mydt),  thelatemail(mydt))
# Unit: milliseconds
#              expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
#      JCWong(mydt) 32.80524 33.49849 35.22232 34.11636 35.70609  47.31256   100  a 
# thelatemail(mydt) 56.55455 57.38479 61.51967 58.05206 59.51973 124.02087   100   b
```

Increasing column count:

```
mydt
new <- replicate(30, sample(1:10, n, replace = T))
mydt <- cbind(mydt, as.data.table(new))
all.equal(JCWong(mydt),  thelatemail(mydt))

system.time(JCWong(mydt)) #0.85 
system.time(thelatemail(mydt)) #7.05 

tr <- microbenchmark(JCWong(mydt),  thelatemail(mydt), times = 10)
ggplot2::autoplot(tr)
# Unit: milliseconds
#              expr       min       lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
#      JCWong(mydt)  817.0644  830.729  866.6022  866.8088  878.4169  982.3655    10  a 
# thelatemail(mydt) 6944.5352 7083.121 7203.8255 7186.6229 7241.6905 7518.9050    10   b
```

It looks like your approach is quite fast. Maybe you could describe the size of your data?